# Remove first occurance of <p> from string

Tags: jquery, regex

Below is the code

```
 var str = '<p>first occurrence</p> can have multiple lines of ln or new line code etc <p>another p</p> and then again <p>another code in p </p>';
```

expected result with regex or simple jquery:

```
 first occurrence can have multiple lines of ln or new line code etc <p>another p</p> and then again <p>another code in p </p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var str = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.trim();
// var str = '<p>first occurrence</p> can have multiple lines of ln or new line code etc <p>another p</p> and then again <p>another code in p </p>';

str = str.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/, '$1');
 
console.log(str);
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <p>first occurrence</p> can have multiple lines of ln or new line code etc <p>another p</p> and then again <p>another code in p </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str=str.replace("<p>","").replace("<\/p>","");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use regex on html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175966) ... put the string into a newly created element and manipulate that element

```
var $div = $('<div>').html(str);
$div.find('p:first').unwrap()
str = $div.html()
```